# Plugin to email a post or page to someone

Tags: plugins, email

Is there a plugin that will allow visitors to email a page or post to someone? I found [WP-EMail](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-email/) but it was updated last on April 2010 so I'm not sure if I should use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the social media sharing plugins include an email option. I know sharedaddy (within jetpack) has a link that allows a permalink to be emailed to a given address.